# Update form row in php error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update multiple row/rows in my form. I'm getting the error `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp.....`

I'm also getting another error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\....`

Both of these are now fixed.

**Form**

```
$ad = "<form action='updaterecords.php' method='post' id='update'> \n";

        $records = $this->query_recs();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $ad .= "<p id='id{$record->id}'>";
            $ad .= "<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='" .$this->render_i18n_data($record->id) . "' />\n";
            $ad .= "<input type='text' name='paname[]' value='". $this->render_i18n_data($record->pa_name) . "' class='paname' />\n";
            $ad .= "<input type='text' name='pcname[]' value='". $this->render_i18n_data($record->pc_name) . "' class='pcname' />\n";
            $ad .= "<input type='text' name='pdname[]' value='". $this->render_i18n_data($record->pd_name) . "' class='pdname' />\n";
            $ad .= "<input type='text' name='pfname[]' value='". $this->render_i18n_data($record->pf_name) . "' class='pfname' />\n";

            $ad .= "<input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' />";
            $ad .= "</p>";
        }

        echo($ad);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

include 'dbdetails.php';

$con = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id         = $_POST['id'];
    $paname = $_POST['paname'];
    $pcname     = $_POST['pcname'];
    $pdname = $_POST['pdname'];
    $pfname    = $_POST['pfname'];

    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE wp_pbcbc_records
                    SET pa_name = '$paname', pc_name='$pcname', pd_name='$pdname', pf_name='$pfname'
                    WHERE id = '$id' ");   

    header("location: localhost/myp");
    exit;
}   
?>
```

---

Update: This has now been solved. Thanks to the people who gave me an answer!

Comment: All the `$_POST` variables are arrays, you have to loop over them.

Comment: When the name of the input ends in `[]`, PHP turns it into an array of all the rows.

Comment: How do I loop over them? @Bamar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note:

- You passed values in array. You must run them in a loop before using them in your query.
- On top of your `isset()` function, there must have no output of HTML entities, which is the common reason for `header()` function to fail and cause an error.

Your connection to your database:

```
include("dbdetails.php");

$con = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db); /* MAKE SURE THAT THE VALUES OF YOUR VARIABLES ARE CORRECT CORRESPONDING TO YOUR DATABASE */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Your updated code:

```
/* THERE MUST HAVE NO OUTPUT IN THIS SECTION TO FIX THE HEADER ERROR */

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

  $counter = count($_POST["paname"]);

  for($x = 0; $x<=$counter; $x++){

    if(!empty($_POST["paname"][$x])){

      $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id'][$x]);
      $paname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['paname'][$x]);
      $pcname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pcname'][$x]);
      $pdname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pdname'][$x]);
      $pfname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pfname'][$x]);

      mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE wp_pbcbc_records
                    SET pa_name = '$paname', pc_name='$pcname', pd_name='$pdname', pf_name='$pfname'
                    WHERE id = '$id' ");   

    } /* END OF IF CHECKING paname */

  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

  header("location: localhost/myp");
  exit;
} /* END OF ISSET */
?>
```

On the side note:

- You must use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize the values of your variables before using them in your query to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
- Better recommendation, is to use `mysqli_* prepared statement`. It will sanitize the variables automatically and no need to escape the strings per variable.

Your code using `mysqli_* prepared statement`:

```
/* THERE MUST HAVE NO OUTPUT IN THIS SECTION TO FIX THE HEADER ERROR */

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

  $counter = count($_POST["paname"]);

  for($x = 0; $x<=$counter; $x++){

    if(!empty($_POST["paname"][$x])){

      if($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE wp_pbcbc_records SET pa_name=?, pc_name=?, pd_name=?, pf_name=? WHERE id=?")){

        $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$_POST["paname"][$x],$_POST["pcname"][$x],$_POST["pdname"][$x],$_POST["pfname"][$x],$_POST["id"][$x]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

      } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

    } /* END OF IF CHECKING paname */

  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

  header("location: localhost/myp");
  exit;
} /* END OF ISSET */
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! @Logan Wayne I'm going to try it this way aswell!

Comment: Whats the difference between the mysqli prepared statement and mysqli real escape string? Which is better to use?

Comment: @crsMC `mysqli_* prepared statement` is way better to use

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer! No errors now but one thing, my database is not been updated, but it is connecting to it? I'm also using this with wordpress, I forgot to mention, its a plugin. The form and the php are both in separate files.

Comment: @crsMC - if your established connection is right. And if your table and column names used in your query are correct. Then it will connect to your database.

Comment: @crsMC - Make sure that there are data inside the passed data. For a simple troubleshoot, hide the `header()` function, and echo the passed data. Here, you will see if there are data really passed on.

Comment: Ok, it's updating now, I had the wrong amount of s's in my ssssi, my bad. But now, it's updating all the rows in my database? It just deleted all my test info

Comment: `s` stands for `strings`. `i` stands for `int`. You will bind five variables in your query and correspond them with the necessary parse, so that is why it is `ssssi`

Comment: It's working, my error again, I forgot to add the where clause. Thanks very much, you helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

Since you used names ending with `[]` in your form, the `$_POST` variables become arrays, and you have to loop over them.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare("UPDATE wp_pbcbc_records
                SET pa_name = ?, pc_name=?, pd_name=?, pf_name=?
                WHERE id = ? ");  
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $cur_paname, $cur_pcname, $cur_pdname $cur_pfname, $cur_id);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $++) {
    $cur_paname = $paname[$i];
    $cur_pcname = $pcname[$i];
    $cur_pdname = $pcname[$i];
    $cur_pfname = $pcname[$i];
    $cur_id = $id[$i];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```